# TIMESTAMP Field - UTC <> Local TimeZone

Tags: mysql, time, mysql-8.0

Referring to Timestamp Lookups Documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/timestamp-lookups.html

In the documentation there is an example how UTC to Local TimeZone can cause descrepenices

Specically this calculation :
Documentation verbiage `The following example shows distinct UTC values that become identical in a non-UTC time zone:`

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE tstable (ts TIMESTAMP);
mysql> SET time_zone = 'UTC'; -- insert UTC values
mysql> INSERT INTO tstable VALUES
       ('2018-10-28 00:30:00'),
       ('2018-10-28 01:30:00');
mysql> SELECT ts FROM tstable;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2018-10-28 00:30:00 |
| 2018-10-28 01:30:00 |
+---------------------+
mysql> SET time_zone = 'MET'; -- retrieve non-UTC values
mysql> SELECT ts FROM tstable;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2018-10-28 02:30:00 |
| 2018-10-28 02:30:00 |
+---------------------+
```

First and foremost

> > DST switch happened on `March 25th @ 2 AM` , meaning MET Time @ 2 AM became 3 AM as shown in screenshot below

Not lets look at the caluation ::

When the timezone is changed to non-UTC that MET which is 1 hour ahead of UTC

| MET | UTC | DST Applied |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/25 00:00 | 10/24 23:00 | NO |
| 10/25 01:00 | 10/25 00:00 | NO |
| 10/25 01:59 | 10/25 00:59 | NO |
| 10/25 03:00 | 10/25 01:00 | YES 2AM -- forward by 1 hour -- so it becomes 3 AM |

So `00:30` UTC --> MET Time should be `01:30` -- `1 hour ahead before 2AM MET`
and `01:30` should become `02:30` or `03:30` ?

There is no time posting of `2AM to 2:59AM` in MET for the day light switch. It will show 3AM as timestamp.

Where is bug in my analysis ?

[image]

- Correct my calulations
- Mysql8 documnentation has to be corrected

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to account for end of the DST. So March is start month for it but it ends in October. So first clock moves forward, effectively "losing" an hour (which can result in a "jump" in local time i.e. from 1:59 AM directly to 3:00 AM as there's no 2:00 AM). But in October it clock moves back, effectively "gaining" an hour back, but that can cause an hour to "repeat" in local time, as opposed to "lost" hour example. So your SQL examples are perfect illustration of and are just fine.